# Python regex - find distinct pattern with metacharacters

Tags: python, regex

I need to translate a pseudo-regex pattern like `A\/*\/B\/*\/C` into regex to create match/no match decisions on paths. The * serve as meta-characters, which match to any set of strings or numbers between forward slashes. The regex above is 'field sensitive', ie it should only match to strings with that exact sequence of specific or meta characters between the forward slashes.  So, `A\/*\/B\/*\/C` (A 1st, then anything 2nd, B 3rd, then anything 4th, C 5th) should match to `'A/foo/B/bar/C'`  as A appears 1st, anything 2nd, B 3rd, etc. but not `A/foo/bar/B/baz/C` as A appears 1st, and B apperas 4th- not 3rd, where we want it.

I've worked on solutions to this problem outside regex, but want to see if there's a regex-only solution.

So far, I have this:

```
import re
matcher=re.compile('[A\/(.*?)\/B\/(.*?)\/C]')
matched=matcher.match('A/foo/bar/B/baz/C')
print matched 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x005CBBB8>
print matched.group()
A
```

As you can see, the problem is that it matches `A/foo/bar/B/baz/C` as it doesn't care that another slash appears between A and B. Thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: You surely don't want to use character classes here.  `[...]` is a character class.  It's used for things like `[a-z]` matches any lowercase letter.  A character class matches exactly one character.  Print out what `matched` matched!

Comment: fixed. that was a typo. And showed what `matched`printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this

```
 //   ^A(?!/B/)/[^/]*/B(?!/C/)/[^/]*/C$

 ^             # BOL
 A             # A
 (?! /B/ )     # Not /B/
 / [^/]* /     #   / ... /
 B             # B
 (?! /C/ )     # Not /C/
 / [^/]* /     #   / ... /
 C             # C
 $             # EOL
```